# Keep confusing different cabals (cabal, cabal-dev, cabal-install and $HOME:/.cabal/bin/cabal)

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal

I keep confusing

1. `cabal` from `/usr/local/bin/cabal`
2. `cabal-dev`
3. `cabal-install`
4. `cabal` in `~/.cabal/bin/cabal` which is used for creating a `sandbox`.

So far I've been using `cabal` (from `/usr/local/bin/cabal)` and `~/.cabal/bin/cabal` - the first one for creating a `.cabal` file by `cabal init`, the second one for creating a sandbox by `cabal sandbox init` and installing the dependencies by `cabal install --only-dependencies`.

So now I want to begin using **only one** of these tools - whatever is more modern and should be used. I believe this is `~/.cabal/bin/cabal`

So I've added `~/.cabal/bin` to `$PATH` and performed `cabal sandbox init`. It worked fine. But `cabal install --only-dependencies` said 
`cabal: No cabal file found.` Why is that? According to this tutorial http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html it doesn't have to be like that.

Anyway, what have I done wrong and what should I do?

**UPDATE**:

```
$ which cabal
/Users/alex/.cabal/bin/cabal
```

But I wonder, does `cabal sandbox init` have to create a .cabal file? The documentation does prove that and the error is:

```
cabal: No cabal file found.
Please create a package description file <pkgname>.cabal
```

Comment: Try giving it's complete path: `~/.cabal/bin/cabal install --only-dependencies` ?

Comment: @Sibi which cabal returns ~/.cabal/bin/cabal

Comment: Thanks, But what does it happen when you give full path during sandbox installation: `~/.cabal/bin/cabal install --only-dependencies` ? I think it should work when you give the full path.

Comment: @Sibi Guess what? The same thing, of course. Are you sure that "cabal sandbox init" should generate .cabal file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run `cabal init` to create a *pkgname*.cabal file?  All of the examples that you liked they always do `cabal install --only dependencies` in an existing source tree, assuming the existence of a *pkgname*.cabal file.

Comment: No I did not. Why no one of them said to do so? I thought I should run either cabal sandbox init or cabal init.

Comment: `cabal sandbox init` creates a new sandbox, which may be for a new or existing project.  `cabal init` is the wizard for creating a new *pkgname*.cabal file, a process that doesn't interact with the sandbox as it is independent of the installed packages.  They are orthogonal, and the similar parts of the command are similar for the same reason they are similar to `git init`.